# Cannot pull correct memory being used

Tags: linux, bash, math

Currently creating a script that will record CPU and memory currently being used every second until you hit a key, which will then graph the results via gnuplot. I cannot seem to figure out how to pull the correct percentage of memory being used. The command I currently have down is...

```
echo "(free | grep Mem | awk '${print $3/$2 * 100"%"}')"
```

This displays the current amount of memory that is free and gives me the following results...
ex.

```
97.0305%
98.06%
94.07%
87.950%
```

I do not need to have the amount that is free being displayed, but the current amount being used. It should be pretty simple to take that number and subtract it from 100 (setting it as a variable or something), but what I would like would be to keep it in a one line echo command like I have above. Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: "Any suggestions" - Subtract... It seems you can divide and multiply... do you have a subtraction phobia or what?

Comment: I have been trying to get the right syntax, but have been failing all morning. I can easily accomplish this using 2 lines of code (one setting up how much is free and the second subtracting from 100 to get the percent being used. As I have stated in my question, I would like to keep it in one line of code. I have not been able to figure out the correct code/syntax for this which is why I asked my question here.

Comment: Found this while searching around:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14102/real-memory-usage

Comment: Thank you for the link user563*.

Comment: The command you are showing will simply `echo` a static string.  Probably you have `echo $(free ... | awk ...)` which is of course better written simply `free ... | awk ...` without the [useless `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it's easy

```
echo "(free | grep Mem | awk '${print (100 - ( ($3/$2) * 100) ) "%"}')"
```

and I don't think you need the `echo "..."` wrapper, try

```
free | grep Mem | awk '{print (100 - ( ($3/$2) * 100) ) "%"}'
```

and you don't need the grep ;-) ,  try

```
free | awk '/Mem/{print (100 - ( ($3/$2) * 100) ) "%"}'
```

and to have the absolute minimum of code, as  Karoly Horvath reminds us, (in this case) "All the parentheses are unnecessary", you  can use

```
free | awk '/Mem/{print 100 - $3/$2 * 100 "%"}'
```

Sorry, but I don't have a system I can test this on right now.

IHTH

Comment: All the parentheses are unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      15360000    5837240    9522760          0    1202040    2490640
-/+ buffers/cache:    2144560   13215440
Swap:      1048568          0    1048568
```

Why not use the 4th column (free) instead? Also, you don't need that grep. Example:

```
$ while true; do awk '/Mem/{printf "\r"$4/$2*100"%"}' <(free); done
62.0591%
```

** note use the \r only if you want to overwrite the previous output and don't use "while true" - it's just an example.

Happy hacking!

EDIT: I completely misread your question, disregard me :(

This will provide you with the current actual usage, according to free, with the buffers/cache removed:

```
awk '/Mem/{t=$2;getline;print $3/t*100"%"}' <(free)
13.9609%
```

Comment: From my understanding, "free" does not appropriately represent how much memory is actually "free" and "usable". The memory inside of "cached" is in a sense free and can be used by any applications that needs it. Perhaps my knowledge is off? I am trying to determine the percent of my memory being used.